# Можно ли навести фокус на текст?

Tags: javascript

```js
document.querySelector('p').onfocus = function() {
    
    alert('фокус');

}
```

```html
<p>текст</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, только сначала для `p` нужно задать `tabindex`:

```js
document.querySelector('p').onfocus = function() {
  console.log('фокус');
}
```

```html
<p tabindex="-1">текст</p>
```